# JQuery Pick-a-Color plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this working great:

http://lauren.github.io/pick-a-color/

However I would like it to pass RGB values instead of Hex when a user clicks on a colour. I know how to parse the hex and convert to rgb, but i would rather skip this and use rgb directly from the page.

Any pointers would be fantastic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the link you provided:

> Accepts HEX, RGB, HSL, HSV, HSVA, and names, thanks to Brian Grinstead's amazing Tiny Color.

You can try it in the example widgets on the page, just input:

```
rgb(255,255,255)
```

**Edit:**

Looking deeper at their API, i feel that they are lacking in callback hooks for their plugin to really be useful for developers to incorporate into their projects. That having been said, you could make a new setting for the callback, and then call it in the internal callback for selecting a color / hiding the modal.

Short of modifying the source code or contributing to that project, you may look to another color picker. I've personally had really great luck with [spectrum](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/). It even has an option to set your [preferred format](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/#options-preferredFormat).

The one thing that these libraries have in common, is they are built on top of [Tiny Color](https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor). Depending on how much interaction you want with your color picker, you might decide to roll your own, or theme spectrum.

Comment: Aye, it accepts rbg from the user. However if you open the drop down and select a colour, it saves the local value as a Hex. Having looked through the code for the pick-a-color js file I think it will take quite a large amount of rewriting to convert it to using rgb. May have to call this one beat and convert it manually

Comment: Not sure if SO alerts the OP when an answer is edited. I added another library to look into using. I'm not sure about your reasons for choosing pick a color, but you might look to more functional robustness in a different library